# pxssh does not work between compute nodes in a slurm cluster

Tags: python, slurm, pxssh

I'm using the following script for connecting two compute nodes in a slurm cluster.

```
from getpass import getuser
from socket import gethostname
from pexpect import pxssh
import sys 

python = sys.executable
worker_command = "%s -m worker" % python + " %i " + server_socket
pid = 0
children = []
for node, ntasks in node_list.items():
        if node == gethostname():
                continue
        if node != gethostname():
                pid_range = range(pid, pid + ntasks)
                pid += ntasks
                ssh = pxssh.pxssh()
                ssh.login(node, getuser())
                for worker in pid_range:
                        ssh.sendline(worker_command % worker + '&')
                children.append(ssh)
```

`node_list` is a dictionary `{'cn000': 28, 'cn001': 28}`. `worker` is a python file placed in the working dictionary.

I expect `ssh.sendline` to be the same as `pexpect.spawn`. However, nothing happened after I ran the script.

Although an ssh session was built by `ssh.login(node, getuser())`, it seems the line `ssh.sendline(worker_command % worker)` has no effect, because the script to be run by `worker_command` is not run.

How can I fix this? Or should I try something else?

How can I create one socket on one compute node and connect it with a socket on another compute node?

Answer (score 0):

There is missing a '%s' from the content of worker_command. It contains something like this: "/usr/bin/python3 -m worker" -> worker_command%worker should result in error.

If not (it is possible, because this source looks like a short part of the original program), then add ">>workerprocess.log 2>&1" string before '&', then try to run your program and take a look at workerprocess.log on the server! If your $HOME is writable on the server, you should find the error message(s) in it.

Comment: Sorry, it was my mistake, the `worker_command` I used is actually `"%s -m worker" % python + " %i " + server_socket`...

Comment: O.K., and what about the log file?